# How to align 3D contour file, aerial imagery and design drawings from engineers in microstation v8i series 3.

Tags: imagery, contour, overlay, aerial-photography, microstation

I am looking to align a 3D contour dgn file with the design drawings from an engineer in microstation.

Then align an orthorectified aerial image (Scale 1:10 000) to the contour file and design drawing file.

I want to do all this in microstation V8i series 3. And avoid aligning the files in a GIS software.

Please advice on steps to follow.